# Is there a good patterns for distributed software and one backend database for this problem?

Tags: java, design-patterns, distributed-computing

I'm looking for a high level answer, but here are some specifics in case it helps, I'm deploying a J2EE app to a cluster in WebLogic. There's one Oracle database at the backend.

A normal flow of the app is
- users feed data (to be inserted as rows) to the app
- the app waits for the data to reach a certain size and does a batch insert into the database (only 1 commit)

There's a constraint in the database preventing "duplicate" data insertions. If the app gets a constraint violation, it will have to rollback and re-insert one row at a time, so the duplicate rows can be "renamed" and inserted.

Suppose I had 2 running instances of the app. Each of the instances is about to insert 1000 rows. Even if there is only 1 duplicate, one instance will have to rollback and insert rows one by one.

I can easily see that it would be smarter to re-insert the non-conflicting 999 rows as a batch in this instance, but what if I had 3 running apps and the 999 rows also had a chance of duplicates?

So my question is this: is there a design pattern for this kind of situation?

This is a long question, so please let me know where to clarify. Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
The 1000 rows of data is in memory for each instance, but they cannot see the rows of each other. The only way they know if a row is a duplicate is when it's inserted into the database.

And if the current application design doesn't make sense, feel free to suggest better ways of tackling this problem. I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by inserting rows in batches of 1000 rather than individually?

Comment: According to my DBA, batch insertion increases performance because we handle millions of rows daily.

Comment: It is unclear from the question if data is collected in memory and if the same data can be collected on the multiple nodes.

Comment: BTW, 1M of rows is just about 11 rows per second for 24h day or 34 rows per second for 8h day, which isn't too much for a modern hardware.

Comment: Then I might have got the numbers wrong. But the concern is performance anyway. I'll edit the question to clarify also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=329

Comment: Wow, this is new for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to avoid parallel processing of the same data. For example, your size or time based event could run only on one node or post a massage to a JMS queue, so only one of the nodes would process it (for instance, by using similar duplicate-check, e.g. based on a timestamp of the message/batch).